# Is there a way to prompt for multiple file select and assign those files (and paths) to a variable?

Tags: matlab, variables, user-interface, getfiles

Is there a way to prompt for multiple file select and assign those files (and paths) to a variable?  For example, bring up a dialogue box that starts you in a base directory, and then allows you to assign files you select to different variables?  Currently I have the paths and files hard coded in but this doesnt allow for any variety in the end.  The other method i was using was using 24 instances of uigetfile, but this was tedious and time consuming so i swapped back to using hard coded file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reread the [uitgetfile documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/uigetfile.html), there is an option to allow multiselect files:

> `[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile(...,'MultiSelect',selectmode)` opens the dialog in multiselect mode. Valid values for `selectmode` are `'on'` and `'off'` (the default, which allows single selection only). If `'MultiSelect'` is `'on'` and you select more than one file in the dialog box, then `FileName` is a cell array of strings. Each array element contains the name of a selected file. Filenames in the cell array are sorted in the order your platform uses. Because multiple selections are always in the same folder, `PathName` is always a string identifying a single folder.